# What does the star that appears next to my Journeyman Craftables mean?

Tags: diablo-iii

Some of my craftable items have a star by their name, what does this signify?

[image: What's with the star?]

Much like my last question, I searched and found no questions pertaining to this. Hopefully this one fares better than my last.

I see the star only appears next to the Journeyman Crafts. Whats a Journeyman Item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means it's a new recipe after you recently trained your artisan. If you close it and re-open the star should be gone.

Journeyman is simply a certain tier of your artisan after you trained him sufficiently.

Comment: Does the fact that the item is Journeyman Signify something?

Comment: They're higher level than apprentice and will cost more both in materials and gold.